# Date format changes after 12th of every month

Tags: python, pandas

I am transforming my date field in dataframe like this

```
df3['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['transaction_date']).dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata').dt.strftime(
                                                    '%d/%m/%Y').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date())
```

But its gives an output like this in csv:

```
transaction_date
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
13/06/23
06/12/23
06/12/23
06/12/23
06/12/23
06/12/23
06/12/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/11/23
06/10/23
06/10/23
06/10/23
06/10/23
06/10/23
06/10/23
```

where the format should always be like 13/06/23 (dd/mm/yy)but as soon as the date drops below 13 it converts it to 06/12/23(mm/dd/yy)
how to solve this such that it gives dd/mm/yy every time?

Comment: Why convert the time object into a string then back into a time object? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: How looks input data?

Comment: Maybe help use `df3['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['transaction_date'], dayfirst=True)` - add `dayfirst='True'` parameter

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
swap = df['transaction_date'].str.replace(r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', r'\2/\1/\3', regex=True)
date = df['transaction_date'].mask(df['transaction_date'].str[:2].astype(int).gt(12), other=swap)
df['transaction_date2'] = pd.to_datetime(date, format='%m/%d/%y')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   transaction_date transaction_date2
0          13/06/23        2023-06-13
1          13/06/23        2023-06-13
2          13/06/23        2023-06-13
3          13/06/23        2023-06-13
4          13/06/23        2023-06-13
5          13/06/23        2023-06-13
6          13/06/23        2023-06-13
7          13/06/23        2023-06-13
8          13/06/23        2023-06-13
9          13/06/23        2023-06-13
10         13/06/23        2023-06-13
11         06/12/23        2023-06-12
12         06/12/23        2023-06-12
13         06/12/23        2023-06-12
14         06/12/23        2023-06-12
15         06/12/23        2023-06-12
16         06/12/23        2023-06-12
17         06/11/23        2023-06-11
18         06/11/23        2023-06-11
19         06/11/23        2023-06-11
20         06/11/23        2023-06-11
21         06/11/23        2023-06-11
22         06/11/23        2023-06-11
23         06/11/23        2023-06-11
24         06/11/23        2023-06-11
25         06/10/23        2023-06-10
26         06/10/23        2023-06-10
27         06/10/23        2023-06-10
28         06/10/23        2023-06-10
29         06/10/23        2023-06-10
30         06/10/23        2023-06-10
```