# Date conversion error in DataFrame in pandas, can anyone point why this issue is happening and how to fix it

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, string-to-datetime

i am trying to convert my two date columns in my dataframe. however some of the date is converted using "%d/%m/%Y" and a few of the data is getting converted using "%m/%d/%Y" . the issue is happening only from 01-May-2023 to 12-May-2023. from 13 may it is again reverting to using "%d/%m/%Y".

I am using the following to convert my data:

```
columns_to_convert_to_date= ['Date','Value Dt']
regex_pattern = r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}'
for column in columns_to_convert_to_date:
        full_bank_df_hdfc[column] = full_bank_df_hdfc[column].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y', errors='coerce') if re.match(regex_pattern, str(x)) else pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce'))
```

screenshot
data before transformation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBKXC.jpg)

data after transformation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAy7q.jpg)

i have tried to force it to use the format to no avail. when using only

`pd.to_datetime(full_bank_df_hdfc['Date'],format='%d/%m/%y', errors='coerce')`

am i getting the desired output in the column , however that is resulting in my already existing datetime format roes to be NaT

1043   2023-04-30
1044   2023-05-01
1045   2023-05-01
1046   2023-05-01
1047   2023-05-02
1048   2023-05-02
1049   2023-05-03
1050   2023-05-03
1051   2023-05-03
1052   2023-05-04
1053   2023-05-04
1054   2023-05-06
1055   2023-05-06
1056   2023-05-07
1057   2023-05-08

Comment: I answered the same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76470553/15239951

Comment: @Corralien Thanks for answer. on a side note i have both datetime and "%d/%m/%Y" in my dataframe. how to handle that so i dont get error using your steps   
0       2022-04-01 00:00:00
1       2022-04-01 00:00:00
2       2022-04-02 00:00:00
3       2022-04-02 00:00:00
4       2022-04-02 00:00:00
               ...         
1084               24/05/23
1085               24/05/23
1086               24/05/23
1087               24/05/23
1088               24/05/23

Comment: Do you mean you have 3 different formats in your dataframe: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`, `'%d/%m/%y'` and `'%m/%d/%y'`?

Comment: i only have two `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` and `'%d/%m/%Y'`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to match the year part on 4 digits but your screenshot show only 2 digits for year?

Try:

```
columns_to_convert_to_date= ['Date','Value Dt']
regex_pattern = r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})'
for column in columns_to_convert_to_date:
    dt = df[column].str.replace(regex_pattern, r'20\3-\2-\1 00:00:00', regex=True)
    df[column] = pd.to_datetime(dt)
```

Output:

```
# Before
>>> df
                     Date             Value Dt
0     2022-04-01 00:00:00  2022-04-01 00:00:00
1     2022-04-01 00:00:00  2022-04-01 00:00:00
2     2022-04-02 00:00:00  2022-04-02 00:00:00
3     2022-04-02 00:00:00  2022-04-02 00:00:00
4     2022-04-02 00:00:00  2022-04-02 00:00:00
1084             24/05/23             24/05/23
1085             24/05/23             24/05/23

# After
>>> df
           Date   Value Dt
0    2022-04-01 2022-04-01
1    2022-04-01 2022-04-01
2    2022-04-02 2022-04-02
3    2022-04-02 2022-04-02
4    2022-04-02 2022-04-02
1084 2023-05-24 2023-05-24
1085 2023-05-24 2023-05-24
```